Weird Grey Circle in Background While in Camera View
Hello Blender Community,
I have this weird grey circle in the background while (ONLY) in Camera View.

I tried:

Adjusting Clipping Space (But it is not a huge scene anyways)
rotating the camera (it is not dependent on the rocks or the lighting it seems)
changing focal length, focus distance

I am sure it is because I use my own "Skybox-Sphere" instead of putting the milkyway texture as the World Texture, but I need it this way, because World Texture cannot be scaled or repeated for some reason and 8k apparently is not enough resolution.

Some additional info in case of relevance:






As @Crantisz shows in his answer, you are setting viewport clipping distances, not the ones for the camera. But I just wanted to point out, if you leave the viewport clipping at these extreme values (especially when it's not a huge scene as you said), then you will most likely get weird artifacts when working in the viewport in Solid shading. I always say a good range is a factor of 10^3 to 10^5 between start and end value is okay, like 0.01 / 1000 or 1 /10000 etc. But of course your scene should fit within this range.

Thank you very much! You mean like z-fighting?

Not exactly, this is called Depth Buffer Glitches and other than Z-Fighting it happens even though there is no overlapping geometry occupying the same space.

Got you. I could witness that.

You are showing Clip Start/End here:

But it doesn't work in camera view. You can edit camera limits in camera data:


I had a feeling it was something like this. Thank you very much! Of course worked like expected!
